# mu4e change column width

Tags: mu4e

I recently switched to mu4e for my mails which is awesome. I changed the date format in the headers view so that it became longer. Unfortunately I cannot see the complete date now because the column width is to small.
How can I change this? How can I change the width of all columns?
Documentation doesn't mention the column width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does customizing [`mu4e-headers-fields`](https://github.com/djcb/mu/blob/c2c5dd59396b6dcc8616c8fbe08e4050c61f7b0a/mu4e/mu4e-headers.el#L50), changing the width corresponding to the `:human-date` "header", do the job? (I haven't tested this.)

Comment: Thx it worked, I was looking for a documentation on this, but not in the comments of the code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Documentation on how to change headers can be found here : https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Longer-configuration.html

Here is the part the op is interested in :

```lisp
;; the headers to show in the headers list -- a pair of a field
;; and its width, with `nil' meaning 'unlimited'
;; (better only use that for the last field.
;; These are the defaults:
(setq mu4e-headers-fields
    '( (:date          .  25)    ;; alternatively, use :human-date
       (:flags         .   6)
       (:from          .  22)
       (:subject       .  nil))) ;; alternatively, use :thread-subject
```

Note that the order of the fields in the code will be the same in the view.